# Is it possible to embed an Android app in a pre-existing app?

Tags: android, android-intent, embed, apk

I would like to inquire if it is possible to embed an Android app in a pre-existing app?

Basically, the parent app will have a set of tabs. Clicking on each tab will open a third-party app within the tab activity. I will access to the third party's apk files but not their source code.

Please advice if this is possible in Android or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to embed the applications, but you can use startActivity or startActivityForResult to launch other applications.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't embed activities in other activities. You can use fragments to do the same thing, but it sounds like that's not what you want.

Comment: You cannot embed fragments from other applications in your own, either.

Comment: In theory, you can instantiate a fragment declared somewhere else. But probably not from an APK